# how can I move a vertex towards the origin?

Tags: transforms

[image]

Good evening,
Can anyone explain me how to move the selected point towards zero through that axis?
(That point is not the object center point)
Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by through the axis. Do you just want to move that vertice to the center?

Comment: What you want to move, where and how? How should linked geometry be moved regarding the selected vertex? Do you want to move shown zigzag of vertices as it is to the 3D cursor? Do you want to move only selected vertex to the cursor? Please [edit] the question.

Answer (score 1):

Snap your cursor to the desired location with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

Set your **Pivot Point** to be the **3D Cursor**

After that, select your first vertex and press <kbd>S</kbd> to scale it toward the 3D Cursor.

Scaling to zero will put the vertex directly on your 3d Cursor.

Comment: Yes thats it! May i ask if i want just move for example 2cm ?

Comment: You can't scale an absolute distance, that's just possible while moving, but you can scale a relative amount of the distance, just by typing a value, e.g. *0.02*.