# move edges radially from the centre

Tags: modeling

I have a shape where I select multiple edges

[image]

I would like to move each of these edges equally in a direction linked to the centre of the object. But as you can see doing this manually causes a mess
[image]

And moving all the edges together causes a different type of mess

[image]

I can achieve something close to what I want by scaling them, but I would like the edges to remain the same length
[image]

Comment: This will create bad geometry. Are you sure you want to do that this way ?

Comment: isn't it the same idea as this question, just moving in the opposite direction? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89871/how-can-i-move-a-vertex-towards-the-origin/89872

Comment: This will still change the length of the edges if i understand that approach correctly. You could otherwise scale all the edges by factor 2 and then change the pivot point to individual origins and scale by factor 0.5 to undo the length change of the previous scaling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone will probably come up with a better way than this...

If you have a lot of work to do in 4-way symmetry, it's probably worth working under a Mirror modifier in X and Y, or an object-offset Array modifier, based on a target rotated by 90 degrees.

For a one-off, though..

- If necessary, create a Custom Orientation from the face the edges have in common
- Set Pivot to Median, or 3D Cursor snapped to the appropriate point
- <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> Scale  the edges outward
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> copy the scale from the Adjust Last Operation panel
- Reset Orientation to Normal, and Pivot to Individual Origins
- <kbd>S</kbd> scale, and in the Adjust Last Operation panel, swipe to select X,Yand Z fields together and type in to one of them:  <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>

Comment: S - scale, Shift Z scales along x and Y only. But this has the same affect as just pressing S?

Comment: @pluke OK, yes, you're right,  in both cases in the answer, so long as the affected components are all at Z=0 in the transformation space (determined by Orientation and Pivot), because 0*anythingyoulike = 0.

Answer (score 1):

- If your pivot for rotation/scaling is "3D Cursor", make sure that the cursor is set appropriately.
- Select all the objects you want to move.
- Hit 'G'
- Hit the letter for the local axis they'll be moving along, twice.

[image]

[Original post on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/2zgw88/how_can_i_scale_objects_from_the_center_point/)

Comment: This is more of a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Sorry, kinda new to SE and the the proper etiquette. Will edit to make it a proper answer. Thanks Nate.

Comment: Thank you for embedding that gif And making this answer pretty for me @ᴊᴀᴄʜʏᴍ ᴍɪᴄʜᴀʟ <3 Not all heroes wear capes

Comment: Happy to help :). Welcome aboard.